# Can't center button to the right in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to center the green `<button>` to the right on medium screens. I tried things like `last:justify-end` on container `<div>` but didn't work (as centering last child will center last `<div>` inside the container `<div>` which contains the green button).

```html
<header>
  <div class="container flex flex-col items-center space-y-3 p-4 md:flex-row">
    <a class="flex items-center space-x-3">
      <span class="text-2xl font-semibold text-orange-500">Hello</span>
    </a>
    <div class="flex space-x-3">
      <button class="cursor-pointer select-none rounded bg-green-500 px-6 py-2 text-white hover:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none">Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/57q0Mm9yTW)

Comment: Why is the post downvoted? it's quite clear and well-researched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the button to be on the right of the screen on medium screen sizes and above.

If that's the case then adding `md:justify-between` to create the space between the elements.

Read more on it [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content#space-between)

Tried uploading the image here, wasn't working.

https://imgur.com/Ade9nSW

```
<header>
  <div class="container mx-auto flex flex-col items-center gap-4 p-4 md:flex-row md:justify-between">
    <a class="flex items-center space-x-3">
      <span class="text-2xl font-semibold text-orange-500">Hello</span>
    </a>
    <div class="flex space-x-3">
      <button class="cursor-pointer select-none rounded bg-green-500 px-6 py-2 text-white hover:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

or

```
<header>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center gap-4 p-4 md:flex-row md:justify-between">
    <a class="flex items-center space-x-3">
      <span class="text-2xl font-semibold text-orange-500">Hello</span>
    </a>
    <div class="flex space-x-3">
      <button class="cursor-pointer select-none rounded bg-green-500 px-6 py-2 text-white hover:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: OK, this works perfectly. Do you know why something like `last:justify-end` didn't work? Also, on somewhat less than medium screens (I guess small screens - before button is placed under orange text), there's small space between button and right side, how to remove it? I tried something like `sm:justify-between` but it didn't work.

Comment: You have `space-y-3` in your parent div, which adds a margin to the y-axis. Remove it by changing it to `space-y-0` or remove it entirely. Meanwhile, `last:justify-end` doesn't work because the div items don't span across the screen. I'll update my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: [Something like this?](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mMUnSn6IeO). [Still doesn't work?](https://ibb.co/nshNH7g).

Comment: Oh! I see what mean. You have `container` as a class and it also scales down. There are two ways of handling this. One is to add `mx-auto` to center the div.

or

remove the `container `class

Comment: My pleasure! Have a nice day as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got the thing for you

```html
<header>
  <div class=" container flex flex-col items-center space-y-3 p-4 md:flex-row">
    <a class="flex items-center space-x-3">
      <span class="text-2xl font-semibold text-orange-500">Hello</span>
    </a>
    <div class="flex space-x-3 max-md:self-end"
      <button class="cursor-pointer select-none rounded bg-green-500 px-6 py-2 text-white hover:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none">Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: [Wrong result?](https://ibb.co/r0y12JX)

Comment: The button is on right as you want on md screen ?

Comment: It's on the left, see the image.

Comment: Where did you put the header component in you code ?

Comment: You said you want button on right when yser is on md screen which 768px and you screenshot is large screen

Answer (score -1):

To center the green `<button>` to the right on medium screens, you can use a combination of utility classes. If you're using a flex container, you can apply the following classes:

```html
<div class="flex justify-between md:justify-end items-center">
  <!-- Other elements on the left -->
  <button class="bg-green-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded">Your Button</button>
</div>
```

In this example:

- `flex` sets the container as a flex container.
- `justify-between` spaces the elements inside the container with maximum space between them.
- `md:justify-end` overrides the `justify-between` on medium screens (`md:` prefix is for medium screens and larger).
- `items-center` centers the items vertically.

Ensure that your container has the appropriate width and that the styles are applied correctly in your CSS or styling framework. Adjust padding and margins as needed for your specific layout.

Comment: Is this a ChatGPT answer? Also I want something specific to my example, since it doesn't explicitly work in this example. I'm probably missing something stupid.